# Statistical model for proportion/percentage

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models, modeling, linear-model

I would like to build a model that would predict a percentage/proportion from another percentage/proportion. More specifically I have medication adherence rates varying from 0 to 1. I can't use linear regression because the adherence rates are non-normally distrubuted, I have a very heavy tail with lower values and a lot of high values. I don't want to categorize the rates either. Which would be optimal model that I could use here?

Comment: How is adherence measured?

Comment: Can you give us information about the samples? It looks like you’re trying to interpolate something so I’m quite tempted to suggest the stuff from Chris on physical informed neural networks for interpolation.  http://chrisrackauckas.com/research.html

Comment: @DemetriPananos adherence is measured by proportion of days covered.